# How to create a value from file to desired format and assign to variable using perl?

Tags: perl

Can someone please let me know how to achieve the below through Perl.

I have a CVS file with values like below.

i/p:

Symbol,A,B,C,D,E,F

66,.8500,.8500,1.1600,1.1600

O/P:

[['Symbol','A','B','C','D','E','F' ],
['66','.8500','.8500','1.1600','1.1600']];

and assign the same to a variable.

How can i able to achieve this through Perl script.

```
$sts = open( CSV, "< File.csv" );

while (<CSV>) {

   $csv = $_;

   chomp($csv);

   @csv_rcd = split( ',', $csv );
   foreach $cell (@csv_rcd) {
      push @rowdata, $cell;
   }

   push @$somedata, @rowdata;

}
```

But the above code didn't produce the desired o/p.

Comment: Added the code, Could you please help me to achieve the desired result.

Comment: What's the problem you're having though? What do you not understand about the result you're getting?

Comment: Hi i want to produce the o/p in this fomat : [['Symbol','A','B','C','D','E','F' ], ['66','.8500','.8500','1.1600','1.1600']]; (from file to variable) through perl. I wrote a code but it;s not working, Can you please help on this.

Comment: "it's not working" is not explaining what problem you're having.

Answer (score 1):

```
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my $somedata;
while (my $csv = <DATA>) {
    chomp $csv;
    push @$somedata, [ split (',' , $csv)];
}
print Dumper($somedata);
__DATA__
Symbol,A,B,C,D,E,F
66,.8500,.8500,1.1600,1.1600
```

Here is a full example to use PDF::Table

```
use PDF::API2;
use PDF::Table;

my $somedata;
while (my $csv = <DATA>) {
    chomp $csv;
    push @$somedata, [ split (',' , $csv)];
}

my $pdftable = new PDF::Table;
 my $pdf = new PDF::API2(-file => "table_of_lorem.pdf");
 my $page = $pdf->page;

$pdftable->table($pdf, $page, $somedata, x => 50, w => 495, start_y => 500, start_h => 300,
    padding => 5, background_color_odd => 'gray', background_color_even => 'lightblue');

$pdf->saveas();

__DATA__
Symbol,A,B,C,D,E,F
66,.8500,.8500,1.1600,1.1600
```

Comment: Does this code produce this o/p: [['Symbol','A','B','C','D','E','F' ], ['66','.8500','.8500','1.1600','1.1600']];

Comment: No. The formating of output can be done with Data::Dumper:my $d = Data::Dumper->new([$somedata]);
$d->Terse(1)->Indent(0);
print $d->Dump, "\n";
This gives exactly the expected format.

Comment: It means that we need to install this Data::Dumper package right? Can't this be done through regular perl scripting?

Comment: Data::Dumper is a core package of Perl that is always present in perl distributions (many packages depend of it). You can do the same with regular perl. It is often given as exercise for learning perl. It requires to learn how to write recursive routine and how to use the ref function (https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ref.html).

Comment: Someone has already asked to rewrite Dumper as homework: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038271/recursively-printing-data-structures-in-perl

Comment: But it's also installed by default, as part of the base perl install

Comment: Hi BOC, Can i pass this "$d->Dump" to Pdf::table method for creating the table in PDF?

Comment: $d->Dump is used to convert from perl data structure to a string. Pdf::table expects a perl data structure. You should pass directly $somedata to Pdf::Table.

Comment: Means you are saying the no need to go for "$d = Data::Dumper->new([$somedata]);"  am i right.